# Multi select checkboxes in service cloud console app

Tags: service-cloud-console

We have a service cloud console app, and we are getting multiple select check boxes in the views. We dont that multi select checkboxes to be visible to users.

Could you please let us know how to disable those.

Answer (score 0):

I've had to enable this in my org for a few Sobjects. The way this works is based on having a button which is a list view button which enables the multi-pick option, and having it on the page layout. So in order to remove this ability you must remove these buttons from the list view page layout. Please go to the appropriate Sobject Search Layout, and modify the list view layout and remove any buttons that have this feature.

IE: If this is contact, please go to setup > contact > search layouts > click edit "contact list view" and uncheck button "add to campaign".